Get the SIP Header for an outgoing request in pjsua2
I'm working with the pjsua2 library to create a sip client and for logging/tracability reasons I would like to read the sip Headers of each incoming and outgoing call.
For incoming calls I managed it over the onIncomingCall callback function in the Account class. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60114704/12558560
But with outgoing calls I'm still not able to monitor them. (They are logged by the standard logging in the console but I can't access them from the code)
I've tried to access the rxdata and the txdata over the prm of the onCallState callback but there the value is almost always null/empty string.
Anyone a clue how I can achieve this?
